# Install PhantomJs on Linux

Tags: phantomjs, redhat

I'm trying to install

```
PhantomsJS
```

on Linux(Red Hat 64 bit) server. Please give me instructions for it?

Comment: Please find the answer. wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo tar -xvf phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
cd phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
cd bin
sudo cp phantomjs /usr/bin
phantomjs -h